# Web User Authentication Alternatives

Tags: email, authentication

I am looking for an alternative to the typical and mainstream username/email password authentication for a user based web site. I was wondering if some alternative to this existed?

Comment: Web authentication can be a broad topic. Any specific constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Besides username/password authentication (typically via a form or using HTTP Basic/Digest authentication), you can use SSL/TLS client certificates when using HTTPS or Kerberos tickets (via SPNEGO).

In addition, there are a number of forms of delegated authentication (which often convey some additional authorisation-related information) such as OpenID, OAuth, SAML/Shibboleth. Depending on the implementation, these may also rely (at the identity provider) on password, certificates or Kerberos, for example.

Comment: Do any sites use like webcam authentication or some form like that or voice or something which you know of?

Comment: I'm not sure. There would be a couple of challenges for this. Firstly, integrating the webcam/audio capture with a website could be a problem (you generally don't want to allow a webpage access to your recording devices just like that, even if some of it is possible, but this could turn out to be more problematic than useful). Secondly, I'd be concerned about the reliability of such authentication mechanisms when opened to the wide internet: visual input for facial recognition can't be that hard to spoof.

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth v2](http://oauth.net) - 
Login via Google/Facebook/Twitter etc.

Or

[Google It](https://www.google.com/search?q=alternative+to+username+password+authentication).

Comment: That is Username and password authentication.

Comment: Not if the user is already logged into the service, reentering password may not even be required depending on the service provier.

Comment: Okey, well I am interested if there exists alternatives.